# How do I create a time frame window for customer purchases from a database where each row is a unique purchase?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery, where each row represents a unique purchase made by a customer. The table has customer ID, what they purchased, when it was purchased and how many times we have seen that customer.

I want to create a table that contains a row of the customers first purchase and anything they bought within 31 days of this purchase.

I also want a new row for their second purchase and again, anything they bought within 31 days of this purchase.

Im trying to see if there are any patterns here, to help drive CRM campaigns.

If this would be easier in python, I can use that also.

I tried using something like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ITEM as FIRST_PURCHASE, t2.ITEM as SECOND_PURCHASE, t3.ITEM as THIRD_PURCHASE
FROM `TABLE` as t1

left join `TABLE` as t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.PURCHASE_NUMBER = t2.PURCHASE_NUMBER+1

left join `TABLE` as t3
on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.PURCHASE_NUMBER = t3.PURCHASE_NUMBER+2

where (t2.DATE_DIFF <= 31) and (t3.DATE_DIFF <= 31)
```

But obviously I only get a 31 day window from the first purchase, and no 31 day windows from any future purhases. I also thought I might be able to attempt this in python using pivot?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can approach it somewhat like this:

```
with purchases as (
  -- dummy column names
  select customerID, item, date, visits from `project.dataset.table`
),
purchase_ordering as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by customerID order by date asc) as rn
  from purchases
),
first_two_purchases as (
  select 
    * except(rn),
    case when rn = 1 then 'First Purchase' else 'Second Purchase' end as purchase_order
  from purchase_ordering 
  where rn <= 2
),
additional_purchase_logic as (
  select
    ftp.purchase_order,
    ftp.customerID,
    ftp.item,
    ftp.date,
    array_agg(struct(p.item,p.date)) as within_31_days_of_purchase
  from first_two_purchases ftp
  left join purchases p using(customer_id)
  where p.date > ftp.date and p.date <= date_add(ftp.date, interval 31 day)
  group by 1,2,3,4
)
select * from additional_purchase_logic
```

Note, if your 2nd purchases is within 31 days of first purchase, it will show up as a subsequent purchase in your 'First Purchase' row as well as an independent record in your 'Second Purchase' row.